# C++: error while declaring a multimap iterator

Tags: c++, templates

I have a stupid problem due to my lack of knowledge about C++ templates.

I have a template class Token and a template class Task.

A Task contains some Token* inside a multimap; and I want to iterate over them.

So, in one of my function, I wrote:

```
template <typename C>
void Task<C>::f() {

    // some code...
    multimap<string, Token<C>* >::iterator it;

}
```

but I get this compilation error from g++:

```
src/structures.cpp:29: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’
```

if I put Token or something like that, it compiles.

Where's the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
 typename  multimap<string, Token<C>* >::iterator it;
```

That error is so common that I think the compiler writers should make it:

```
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’ - did you forget a typename?
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, worked like a charm! So why I need to put "typename" in front of a templatized type if I use inside a template type?

Comment: +1 - I truly wish compilers would give more meaningful error messages for missing `typename`'s, it would save SO hundreds of questions a year.

Comment: @Alexander: I'm sorry, I know it is tedious to see this kind of question over and over again, but it's difficult to find and answer just searching with google :)

Comment: @akappa You need it if the template depends a template parameter of the enclosing function. In this case it does - the `C` parameter.

Comment: @akappa - it's all fine to ask this. `typename` issues are indeed extremely difficult to google if you never heard of this keyword before and they don't qualify as SO duplicates because it's always a bit different. What we need is a) better error messages b) MSVC to implement and enforce `typename`.

Answer (score 2):

I follow a rule always,

**"Whenever you are inside a template function (including its return type) and you are declaring some variable using scope resolution operator ("::"), then always put a typename."**

Declare your variable as,

```
typename multimap<string, Token<C>* >::iterator it;
```